# How to solve this inequality for double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, inequality, self-learning

I have this double integral over a domain which I want to solve:

$$ \int\int_B 1 \ dxdy  \\B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \frac{1}{4} x^2 -1 \leq y \leq 2-x \} $$

So I tried to solve the inequation to get my limits for the integral which is where I failed:

I have cheated by looking at what wolfram-alpha calculates but I have no idea how I come to that result by myself.

$$ \frac{1}{4} x ^2 -1 \leq y \leq 2-x $$
$$ x^2-4 \leq 4y \quad \land  \quad y \leq 2-x $$
$$ x^2 \leq 4y+4 \quad \land \quad x+y \leq 2 $$

I have no idea how I can get further than that.

Also when I try to plug the results which I got from WA into a integration calculator I get not the results which I already had to check my answer for correctness.

I tried to calculate (the values that WA gave me) $$\int_{-6}^2 \int_{\frac{1}{4}x^2-4}^{2-x}1 \ dydx = \frac{136}{3}\neq \frac{-33}{3}$$

How can I solve this inequality and where I my error of thought ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be
$$\iint_B 1 \ dxdy=\int_{-6}^2\left( \int_{\frac{x^2}{4}-1}^{2-x}1 \ dy\right)dx =\int_{-6}^2 \left(3-x-\frac{x^2}{4} \right)dx\\=\left[3x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{12}\right]_{-6}^2=\frac{64}{3}.$$
P.S. Note that
\begin{align*}
&2-x\geq \frac{x^2}{4}-1\Leftrightarrow 2-x-\frac{x^2}{4}+1\geq 0\Leftrightarrow(−1/4)(x^2+4x−12)\geq 0\\
&\Leftrightarrow(x^2+4x−12)\leq 0\Leftrightarrow(x+6)(x-2)\leq 0
\Leftrightarrow x\in[-6,2].
\end{align*}

Comment: im trying to undestand your answer and I dont understand where the $(x+6)$ comesfrom in the second term and why the $\frac{1}{4}$ disappears in the third term

Comment: @zython At the second step, putting all the terms on the left side you obtain $(-1/4)(x^2+4x-12)$. Then factorize $x^2+4x-12$ as $(x+6)(x-2)$. Finally note that $(-1/4)A\geq 0$ iff $A\leq 0$ because $-1/4$ is negative.

Comment: sorry if this question sounds dumb but what do you mean " putting all the terms on the left side" ?

Comment: @zython More details are added to my P.S. in the answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer and your time, this answer makes sense to me know

Comment: @zython Well done! I am glad it helped.